Goldstein Chapter 6 Question
I have a question about a potential error in the $3^{\mathrm{rd}}$ edition of Goldstein's Classical Mechanics. In their exposition in Chapter 6 of small oscillations, the authors obtain the usual result that the problem is equivalent to a generalized eigenvalue problem
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{V}\mathbf{a} = \lambda\mathbf{T}\mathbf{a}
\end{equation*}
for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{a}$. They then go on to "form all the eigenvectors $\mathbf{a}_{k}$ into a square matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with components $a_{jk}$," so that we can write the following relation for the orthonormality of the eigenvectors
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{1},
\end{equation*}
where the tilde denotes the matrix transpose and the right-hand side is the identity matrix of correct dimension.
Immediately afterward, they give a two-dimensional example (p. 245-246) in which they write that two of the orthonormality conditions are
\begin{equation*}
a_{i1}^{2}+a_{i2}^{2} = 1.
\end{equation*}
But the eigenvectors are meant to constitute the columns, so
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{A} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{21}\\
a_{12} & a_{22}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11}^{2}+a_{21}^{2} & a_{11}a_{12} + a_{21}a_{22}\\
a_{12}a_{11} + a_{22}a_{21} & a_{12}^{2}+a_{22}^{2}
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}
Then shouldn't the conditions be
\begin{equation*}
a_{1i}^{2}+a_{2i}^{2} = 1?
\end{equation*}
No mention is made in the published errata of this, so I'm not sure if it is an error or not. If not, am I mistaken in that the eigenvectors should form the columns and not the rows of $\mathbf{A}$?

I will completely agree with you that Goldstein is being particularly unreadable at this point, but it should be clear that you are writing the opposite matrix convention as Golstein is. i.e. it is $\boldsymbol A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{21}\a_{12}&a_{22}\end  {pmatrix}$ rather than the other way around.

@naturallyInconsistent Thank you for checking! Looking back only a few pages at p. 242, equation (6.13), he uses the ordinary convention that $a_{ij}$ refers to row $i$ and column $j$; it's unfortunate the authors decided to change the convention without mentioning it. This example (and the opposite convention) isn't used in the 2nd edition of the book at all, so maybe I'll read about oscillations there instead.

the eigenvalue column vector is norm to 1, thus
$~a_{1i}^{2}+a_{2i}^{2} = 1~$. or $~\mathbf a_i^T,\mathbf a_i~=1$

@Eli I agree! So I think the book's equation is either a mistake, or as naturallInconsistent suggests, maybe the authors are using a strange notation where $a_{ij}$ refers to column $i$ and row $j$.

This equation $~a_{ij}~(V_{ij}-\lambda_i,\delta_{ij}~)=0~$ should be
$~a_{ji}~(V_{ij}-\lambda_i,\delta_{ij}~)=0~$
and $~a_{1i}^2+a_{2i}^2=1~$

starting with matrix notation
with
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbf{V}=\begin{bmatrix}
               V_{11} & V_{1,2} \\
               V_{21} & V_{2,2} \\
             \end{bmatrix}\quad,
\mathbf{\lambda}=\begin{bmatrix}
                    \lambda_1 \\
                    \lambda_2 \\
                  \end{bmatrix}\\
&\mathbf \delta= \begin{bmatrix}
                   1 & 0 \\
                   0 & 1 \\
                 \end{bmatrix}\quad,
\mathbf{a}=\begin{bmatrix}
              a_{11} & a_{12} \\
              a_{21} & a_{22} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
The eigenvectors equations
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\begin{bmatrix}
               V_{11} & V_{1,2} \\
               V_{21} & V_{2,2} \\
             \end{bmatrix}-\lambda_1\,\begin{bmatrix}
                   1 & 0 \\
                   0 & 1 \\
                 \end{bmatrix}\right)\,\begin{bmatrix}
                                         a_{11} \\
                                         a_{21} \\
                                       \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\\\\
&\left(\begin{bmatrix}
               V_{11} & V_{12} \\
               V_{21} & V_{22} \\
             \end{bmatrix}-\lambda_2\,\begin{bmatrix}
                   1 & 0 \\
                   0 & 1 \\
                 \end{bmatrix}\right)\,\begin{bmatrix}
                                         a_{12} \\
                                         a_{22} \\
                                       \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,\Rightarrow\\\\
&\left(V_{ij}-\lambda_1\,\delta_{ij}\right)\,a_{j1}=0\quad, j=1..2\quad,a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2=1\\
&\left(V_{ij}-\lambda_2\,\delta_{ij}\right)\,a_{j2}=0\quad, j=1..2
\quad,a_{12}^2+a_{22}^2=1\\
\end{align*}
thus
\begin{align*}
 & \sum _{i,j}\,a_{ji}\,\left(V_{ij}-\lambda_i\,\delta_{ij}\right)=0\quad,
 a_{1i}^2+a_{2i}^2=1
\end{align*}

Yes, that's what I think, too, but that is not what is in the text. Thank you for your explanation, though! I think it must be an error in the book.

@GeorgyZhukov I think you are right, it is error in the book!
